# Issues with grub menu timeout

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, ssh

I recently installed xubuntu 14.04 on my desktop. The desktop has only one drive containing xubuntu, and I often restart the machine from ssh using the command `sudo reboot now`. However, every other time I do this, grub does not timeout and boot ubuntu, and I must go to the remote machine and tap "enter" on the keyboard to continue the boot process. What is going on here?

Here is my `/etc/default/grub` file, and I called `sudo update-grub` after each time I modified it.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

# advice from irc
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=10
```

Comment: Have you tried activating and using GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT instead?

Answer (score 0):

Mine looks similar to yours and works as advertised. Based on the differences I see I would recommend the following course of action:

0) make a backup copy of /etc/default/grub as in `sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak` So that if an error is made you can revert to the previous file and be no worse off.

1) Place quotes around all non comment values after an = sign

2) Remove or comment out the line `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=10` as it's indicated a problem in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1438275) which is flagged a duplicate of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1443735)

3) run `sudo update-grub` after completing these changes.

Comment: I updated the `/etc/default/grub` file as you specified, ran `sudo update-grub`, then rebooted, and I ran into the same problem. I also noticed that I couldn't select any other options with my keyboard, but was able to press enter and boot. Next, I rebooted a second time, and grub immediately booted into xubuntu without even showing the grub screen- don't I have the timeout set correctly in the above config?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the current `/etc/default/grub`